# Javascript Operator += won't take a negative number

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

EDIT: I believe I found the solution to my problem I am setting velX and velY to zero when either Right or Left is not pressed so I don't know why it won't make moving in all positions impossible but that seems to be the problem, will update with answer

EDIT2: After talking to you guys I determined that it is not a += problem but something else so I made the first edit, and I came up with my answer for my problem here

```
            if (movementDirection.Left) {
                this.velX = -speed * zzoom;
            } else if((movementDirection.Left !== true) && movementDirection.Right !== true){
                this.velX = 0;
            }
            if (movementDirection.Right) {
                this.velX = speed * zzoom;
            } else if((movementDirection.Right !== true) && movementDirection.Left !== true){
                this.velX = 0;
            }
```

this is also along with the velY, **PS** thank's for the down votes....

ORIGINAL POST==========================================================
Hello I am trying to make a smooth moving object when keys are pressed, however the position will not move when a negative number is entered therefore making it impossible to move right and down (I have the directions reversed) here is my code

```
if (movementDirection.Left) {
    console.log(-speed * zzoom);
    this.velX = -speed * zzoom;
} else if (movementDirection.Left != true) {
    this.velX = 0;
}
if (movementDirection.Right) {
    this.velX = speed * zzoom;
} else if(movementDirection.Right != true){
    this.velX = 0;
}

 if (movementDirection.Up) {
     this.velY = -speed * zzoom;
 } else if(movementDirection.Up != true){
     this.velY = 0;
 }

 if (movementDirection.Down) {
     this.velY = speed * zzoom;
 } else if(movementDirection.Down != true) {
     this.velY = 0;
 }

 if (movementDirection.noMovement) {
     this.velX = 0;
     this.velY = 0;
 }
 this.lPosX = this.lPosX + this.velX;
 this.lPosY = this.lPosY + this.velY;
 context.translate(this.velX, this.velY);
```

As you can see there is no reason for this to be happening, I've logged velX when it should be going in the direction when it doesn't move, however if I log this

```
this.lPosX = this.lPosX + this.velX
```

Or this

```
this.lPosX += this.velX
```

I end up with a number that will not be negative, however when I move in a direction that makes it positive it does what it is supposed to but it will not go negative for whatever reason.

Comment: `+=` works fine with negative numbers. Are you sure that `speed` has the correct sign?

Comment: log the velX I do not think it is negative nor the lPosX

Comment: I'm sure of it, unless '-' doesn't work to make it a negative number because I am logging velx and it outputs as -10

Comment: Is `movementDirection.Left === true` when you press left and `movementDirection.Right === true` then you press right?

Comment: [`+=` definitely works with negatives.](https://jsfiddle.net/w7bjwzvz/)  You're not logging at the right time.  To see the problem, you need to log just before you add to the velocity.

Comment: This is the output of my console [link](https://imgur.com/nMz5Fmu) the first and second lines are ' console.log(this.velX)' and 'console.log(-speed * zzoom)' the third is 'console.log(this.lPosX = this.lPosX + this.velX)' I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Do you know how to use your browser's (looks like Chrome) javascript debugger.  I think you'd find it very helpful.

Comment: Sorta. But it won't let me click on alot of the stuff because I am calling the function by updating it with a interval

Comment: Do you know how to set a breakpoint?  If you use a breakpoint, you can enter the debugger whenever the interval fires.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your situation (assuming a number of things) except I can only move right and down.

```js
var context = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
var movementDirection = {
 Left: false,
  Right: false,
  Up: false,
  Down: false,
  noMovement: true
};
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  movementDirection = {
    Left: false,
    Right: false,
    Up: false,
    Down: false,
    noMovement: false
  };
  switch (e.keyIdentifier) {
   case 'Left':
     movementDirection.Left = true;
     break;
      
    case 'Right':
     movementDirection.Right = true;
     break;
      
    case 'Up':
     movementDirection.Up = true;
     break;
      
    case 'Down':
     movementDirection.Down = true;
      break;
      
    default:
     movementDirection.noMovement = true;
      break;
  }
}, false);
var speed = 1;
var zzoom = 1;
var obj = {
  velX: 0,
  velY: 0,
  locX: 125,
  locY: 125,
  draw: function() {
    if (movementDirection.Left) {
      console.log(-speed * zzoom);
      this.velX = -speed * zzoom;
    } else if (movementDirection.Left != true) {
      this.velX = 0;
    }
    if (movementDirection.Right) {
      this.velX = speed * zzoom;
    } else if(movementDirection.Right != true){
      this.velX = 0;
    }

    if (movementDirection.Up) {
      this.velY = -speed * zzoom;
    } else if(movementDirection.Up != true){
      this.velY = 0;
    }

    if (movementDirection.Down) {
      this.velY = speed * zzoom;
    } else if(movementDirection.Down != true) {
      this.velY = 0;
    }

    if (movementDirection.noMovement) {
      this.velX = 0;
      this.velY = 0;
    }
    this.lPosX = this.lPosX + this.velX;
    this.lPosY = this.lPosY + this.velY;
    context.translate(this.velX, this.velY);
  }
};

(function draw() {
  context.fillStyle = '#FFF';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, 250, 250);
  context.fillStyle = '#000';
  obj.draw();
  context.fillRect(obj.locX, obj.locY, 10, 10);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
})();
```

```css
canvas {
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="250" height="250"></canvas>
```

The reason for this is how you're checking for which direction they're going. Take a look at this:

```
if (movementDirection.Left) {
  // Move the character left, that makes sense
  this.velX = -speed * zzoom;
} else if (movementDirection.Left != true) {
  // Stop if they aren't pressing left
  this.velX = 0;
}

if (movementDirection.Right) {
  // Move the character right
  this.velX = speed * zzoom;
} else if (movementDirection.Right != true) {
  // Stop the player, even if they're moving left!
  this.velX = 0;
}
```

You see this same issue in the up/down section. To solve this, simplify the if statements:

```
if (movementDirection.Left) {
  // Move left
  this.velX = -speed * zzoom;
} else if (movementDirection.Right) {
  // Move right
  this.velX = speed * zzoom;
} else {
  // Don't move horizontally at all
  this.velX = 0;
}
```

I'd even take this one step further and use a "direction modifier" when picking up the keyboard input:

```
// When you're getting input
if (holdingLeft) {
  this.xDirection = -1;
} else if (holdingRight) {
  this.xDirection = 1;
} else {
  this.xDirection = 0;
}
```

Then when you're updating their position and velocity:

```
this.velX = this.xDirection * speed * zzoom;
```

Voila! It handles going left or right. Follow the same pattern for vertical movement and you should be golden.